# OneDrive API centralized account

Tags: onedrive

We want to use OneDrive API to upload and retrieve files from our own account.

The problem is that OAuth needs user interaction for login and then redirects back.
However we don't want to each user to log in and then gain access to his account. We want to just communicate with our own onedrive account without user to know about that.

(In other words, we're not creating an application that allow our users to edit their own data, but to interact with our data, like a database.)

Is there any way how to do this with OneDrive or we should use different approach?

Comment: Maarty, I have the same scenario. Did you find a solution?

Comment: We finally chose different implementation that OneDrive. However I believe you can achieve that with resource owner flow of authentication https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm and OneDrive Business

Answer (score 0):

Try adding admin (user used in OAuth) as ‘Site Collection Administrator’ to access all the file/folders of a User.